# PHP Mysql New Row Inserted into database table every time i refresh the page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website with shopping cart, I managed successively add items to basket, but i want the baskets in items to be inserted into orders table in my database at the same time, which works but every time i refresh a page or move around different pages the same items that are currently inside the basked are constantly inserted.

I am allow user to delete items from basket but again i want the same to happen in my database table.

Here is my code please analyze it and point out a solution THX.

cart.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])){
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT product_id, product_qua FROM products WHERE product_id='.$_GET['add']);
    while($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)){
        if($quantity_row['product_qua'] !=$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]){
            $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1'; 
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['add'])){
    $qq = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users');
    while($user_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($qq)){
        $grr = $_SESSION['username'];
        if($user_rows['username'] == $grr){
        $z = $user_rows['first_name'];
        $zz = $user_rows['last_name'];
            }
        }
    $q = mysql_query('SELECT product_name, product_qua, product_price from products WHERE product_id='.$_GET['add']);
    while($prod_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

        $x = $prod_rows['product_name'];
        $xx = $prod_rows['product_price'];
        $xxx = $prod_rows['product_qua'];

        $order = "INSERT INTO orders (order_user_first_name, order_user_last_name, order_product_name, order_product_price, order_product_quantity ) VALUES ('$z','$zz','$x','$xx','$xxx')";
        mysql_query($order);
    }


}



if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['remove']]--;
}
```

The above code is  not all the code from the file but the parts that are responsible of what I am trying to implement

Regards

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), because you current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: 34 questions asked and only 8 answers did help you? that is a bit improbable. with such a stats not many would/should even dare to help you...

Comment: it sounds like you're passing variables around in the url and as you browse the site, those variables are continuing to be passed around. perhaps you should perform a re-direct once the item has been added, so it doesn't maintain the vars?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns redirecting some how worked :o so thx for your suggestion much appreciated........I am aware of mysql injections I 1st want to get things working, what i do i create one functionality make sure it works the i improve the code the i move on to another bit AND last but NOT least ITrobus I see u did ur homework CONGRATULATIONS apply for FBI..........and on the serious side how can i accept some answers that do not fix my issue :)

Comment: @JoshuaBurns not a problem give me a upvote at list in riturn if u wish so :P regards and thx once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're passing variables around in the URL and as you browse the site, those variables are continuing to be passed around. Perhaps you should perform a re-direct once the item has been added, so it doesn't maintain the vars?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing, your code does exactly what you tell it to do. You are using **$_GET** and instead you are posting data into database.

The way i use **$_GET** is when i need to select data or retrieve data from server. I use **$_POST** when i need to post data to the server.

Solution to your problem is to have a script that you POST data into and then have a redirect back to avoid re-insertion into Table.

Comment: ok well changing from get to post did not work but.....but redirecting seems to solve the problem `header('Location: userhome.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Should you try $_POST instead of $_GET maybe?

Comment: ok well changing from get to post causes more problems such as erros an no insertion

Answer (score -1):

Use `$_GET` instead `$_POST`.

Solution to your problem is to have a script that you POST data into and then have a redirect back to avoid re-insertion into Table.

Comment: This question is four years old. Your "answer" is little more than a cut and paste of a paragraph from GGio's answer.